# Output placeholders of modx TV list-box

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources, modx-templates

I am new to modx and have limited knowledge of PHP. I'm writing a snippet and struggling with the syntax. I want to output placeholders of template variable list-box. What I have tried to do is to get the TV list-box IDs and loop through each one returning the html. Not having much luck. Forgive my stupidity.

```
            <?php
            $o='';
            $docid=$modx->resource->get('id');
            $show = $modx->resource->getTVValue('showHideContacts');
            $heading = $modx->resource->getTVValue('contactTitle');

            $staffVar=$modx->getObject('modTemplateVar',26); 
            $staff = $staffVar->getValue($docid);


            if($show =='value1')
            {

            //opening
            $o.='<div class="row">
            <div class="span9">
            <div class="footerContact">
            <h3><i class="icon-mail-circled"></i>'. $heading .'</h3>
            <div class="row">';


            if (!empty($staff)) {
               foreach($staff as $staff) {

                $name = $staff->resource->get('pagetitle');
                $title = $staff->resource->get('longtitle');
                $number = $staff->resource->get('description');
                $email = $staff->resource->get('introtext');

                  $o .= '<div class="span3">
                        <ul class="contactDetails">
                        <li><b>'. $name .'</b></li>
                        <li>'. $title .'</li>
                        <li>'. $number .'</li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:'. $email .'">'. $email .'</a></li>
                       </ul>
                      </div>';
               }
            } 

            //close 
            $o.='
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';


            }
            return $o;
```

Comment: What "staffVar" tv type?

Comment: staffVar is just the variable name of the template variables I'm retrieving. I have already spotted one mistake I have made and that is $staff being an array. I will need to explode it and retrieve the placeholders for each ID

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I wanted. Resorted to PHP and SQL instead of modx syntax.

```
    $staffVar=$modx->getObject('modTemplateVar',26); 
    $staff = $staffVar->getValue($docid);


    if($show =='value1')
    {

    //opening
    $o.='<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
    <div class="footerContact">
    <h3><i class="icon-mail-circled"></i>'. $heading .'</h3>
    <div class="row">';

    $totalContacts = explode("||", $staff);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($totalContacts); $i++){
         $id =$totalContacts[$i];

    $stmt = $modx->query("SELECT pagetitle, longtitle, description,introtext
    FROM $table
    WHERE id=$id
    AND published=1
    AND deleted=0
    ORDER BY menuindex ASC
    "
    );

    if ($stmt && $stmt instanceof PDOStatement) {

        while ($row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


            $o.='<div class="span3">
            <ul class="contactDetails">
            <li><b>' . $row['pagetitle'] . '</b></li>
            <li>' . $row['longtitle'] . '</li>
            <li>' . $row['description'] . '</li>
            <li><a href="mailto:' . $row['introtext'] . '" >'.$row['introtext'] .'</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>';
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is use the getResources plugin, and do a simple 
If i understand your code from the question right your looking at a template variable for the current resource and getting the value of it, you then want to loop the contacts when there are some to loop. This could be easier accomplished with the getResources plugin, used directly in your template. Assuming TV with ID of 26 is a comma separated list of ID's. Otherwise you'd have to rework it into such a list before giving it to `&resources=`

```
[[getResources? &resources=`[[*nameOfTVWithID26]]` &tpl=`yourChunk`]]
```

Where `yourChunk` looks something like

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="contactDetails">
        <li><b>[[+pagetitle]]</b></li>
        <li>[[+longtitle]]</li>
        <li>[[+description]]</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:[[+introtext]]">[[+introtext]]</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This helps you extract your HTML from inside a Snippet, and allows you to skip using the snippet at all. It also makes it easier to expand the function by simply adding some params to your `getResources` instead of having to modify or completely rewrite your custom snippet.